# find whether a string contains any special characters and remove with string.empty c#

Tags: c#, regex

i want to find whether a string contains any of the special characters  like !,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,), ', ",", [ , ] and if it finds these  characters i want to remove those special chars and replace it with string.empty. i ahve gone through one of the posts in this forum and one expert suggests to do the below line of code. But would like to know, after finding the special char.how to rmeove the same. am using c# console appln.

```
 Regex RgxUrl = new Regex("[^a-z0-9]");
 blnContainsSpecialCharacters = RgxUrl.IsMatch(stringToCheck);
```

Comment: add some examples with expected output please...

Comment: Do you want to limit the input to some fixed characters or just remove the above mentioned special characters?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "special" characters. Non-alphanumeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using linq:

```
string StringToCheck = ";#abc@()[]_123-~`";
string newstring = new String(stringToCheck.Where(x => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)).ToArray());
```

### OUTPUT:

> > abc123

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://ideone.com/vJIoTq)

Comment: thanks  very much @Ehsan. i am having another issue related to this. will start new thread for that.

Comment: please help me to let me know where is the mark this answer link.am pretty new to this stackoverflow. i usually use social msdn forums to post my queries. thanks.

Comment: @SaMolPPp click tick mark in left of my posted answer to mark it as answer, and whenever you got answer of your question mark the post as answer which solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
  Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-z0-9]");
  string result = rgx.Replace(stringToCheck, string.Empty);
```